# Keep running command until output differs from previous run in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a script I want to run every x seconds until the output changes. With a simple while or until loop, I know how to check the output for a particular string using grep, but what I want to do is continue iterating the loop until the output from the current iteration does not equal the output from the previous iteration.

How can I achieve this in bash?

The closest I've gotten is below, where the command is run twice in each iteration, but this produces extra runs because the while loop cannot remember the output from the previous iteration.

```
while [ "$(command)" = "$(command)" ]; do sleep 10m; done
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From [`man 1 watch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html#OPTIONS):

> `-g`, `--chgexit`
> Exit when the output of *command* changes.

`watch` is not required by POSIX but it's quite common anyway. In Debian or Ubuntu it's in the `procps` package along with `kill` and `ps` (and few other tools).

Example:

```
watch -g -n 5 'date +%H:%M'
```

Comment: Nice, much simpler than my solution!

Comment: @l0b0 Well, funny thing is I have just learnt `watch` can do this. I was thinking about a script like yours (temporary files? or variables? hashes in variables?) and it occurred to me there already may be a tool that can do this. If anything then `watch`. I checked and here it is.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick - explanations inline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit if any errors occur or any undefined variables are dereferenced
set -o errexit -o nounset

# Store the outputs in a separate directory
output_directory="$(mktemp --directory)"
last_output_file="${output_directory}/last"
current_output_file="${output_directory}/current"
touch "$current_output_file"
ln --symbolic "$current_output_file" "$last_output_file"
# The count is just here to show that we always run at least twice, and that
# after that we run the command a random number of times.
count=0

while true
do
    echo "$((++count))"

    # This is our command; it prints 0 or 1 randomly
    if [[ "$RANDOM" -gt 16383 ]]
    then
        echo 0 > "$current_output_file"
    else
        echo 1 > "$current_output_file"
    fi

    # Abort the loop when the files differ
    if ! diff --brief "$last_output_file" "$current_output_file"
    then
        break
    fi

    # Shunt the current output to the last
    mv "$current_output_file" "$last_output_file"
done
```

There are probably simpler ways to do this, but it has a couple useful features:

- It avoids creating any extraneous files, such as using `mktemp` for every output.
- By starting with the last output file being a symbolic link to the current output file we guarantee that the first `diff` command sees two identical files. This avoids duplicating the command we're testing for, at the expense of one extra `diff` execution.

Comment: It seems to work. `rm -r "$output_directory"` may or may not be desired.

Comment: OP might want to inspect the difference, which is why I left it in.

Comment: I understand. My solution does not allow this. Here you win.

Comment: Can you use `--differences=permanent` to achieve the same thing?

Comment: In my tests `--differences=permanent` doesn't cease repeating the command. The OP explicitly wants to "keep running *until*".

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, `watch` is the way to go here, as described in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1602250/600133). But if you ever do want or need to do this in the shell, here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset prev
while output=$(some_command);
      [ "${prev+set}" != set ] || [ "$output" = "$prev" ];
do
    prev=$output
    sleep 10;
done
```

`"${prev+set}"` expands to `set` if `prev` was set to a value after being unset at the start, so in effect it forces the contents of the loop to run at least once. Alternatively we could just initialize `prev` as `prev=$(some_command)` at the cost of running `some_command` an additional time at the start of the loop.

Also, as noted in comments, command substitution removes all trailing newlines from the command output, so if the only changes in the result are with those, this won't be able to tell the outputs apart. That should rarely matter, though.

Comment: Minor note: command substitution removes trailing empty lines according to the standard.

Comment: @DannyNiu, yes. the question already used comsubs, so I figured that wouldn't be an issue.